# How can preg_replace() be used to limit (not prevent) XSS?

Tags: php

Following along here: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

I didn't quite understand the intent here (my code using part of the above referenced tutorial):

```
// XSS protection to avoid printing the value
/* Developer's Note: Not actually sure what the purpose of this is, or how it protects. */
$id = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $id);
$uname = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $uname);
```

I think I just don't understand reg ex, but my guess is that we are eliminating anything that is not a reasonable alphanumeric character, and in doing so, we are at least limiting the effectiveness of traditional JS  tags.

Comment: read about SQL injections, XSS, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct with the purpose of the regex. It is stripping out any character that is not an alphanumeric, an underscore or a dash (`-`).

This is sufficient protection against XSS as most attacks rely on injecting or storing arbitrary JavaScript strings and that character set is too limited for any effective XSS to be stored.

**Note:** I am saying your **regex** is sufficient. Not necessarily `preg_replace` iteself.

Comment: That's what I thought, so thanks for confirming. That being said, it's hardly sufficient apparently: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzXz0g196qg This vid shows a creative way to get <script> in. However, it's kind of locking the front door. It's hardly sufficient, but it does discourage attacks and/or makes attackers move on to something with less protection.

Comment: @VisWebsoft That video does show an example where the filtering can be bypassed, but the issue there is that the regex is far too complex. I would agree that regex is a bad filter if you are not limiting to a specific character set (which yours is). The method used in the video would not work with the regex you posted. I have added a note to my answer to clear this up.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is only allowing alphanumeric characters, underscores, and dashes.

I'd assume `$uname` and `$id` are user input from a POST, GET, or COOKIE variable.  Hence, this protects you from an XSS if you are printing these variables.  If a user were to inject a script, such as `<script>...</script>`, into the variable, it would strip it down to `script...script` which would protect the output from any malicious injection.